# Where does "send to" "Mail recipient" in Windows 10 file menu temporarily save files?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, windows-explorer, images, right-click

I had learned many years ago that you could quickly shrink the size of multiple photos all at once by selecting them all in a Windows explorer window, right-clicking, and choosing `send to` > `mail recipient`. In doing so, you can select to shrink the photos' sizes all at once, and this happens fairly quickly (without needing to install any additional programs or apps).

My issue: I can't remember (nor quickly determine) where these temporary reduced-sized image files are being stored for me to easily access.

**Question: Where are files temporarily saved that are selected to be sent to an email recipient from an explorer window right-click menu?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppData\Local\Temp** under your user folder.

---

From [here](https://www.diytechguides.com/resize-multiple-images-at-once-in-windows-10.html):

Enter `%temp%` in the Windows search bar. This will pull up the `AppData\Local\Temp` folder.

The resized photos are in this folder. (Search or sort by to find .jpg, etc.).

However, note: the files will all disappear from the temp folder if you close out of the mail warning that pops up after selecting to send to mail recipient:

[image]

or

[image]

So don't click OK on the pop-up until after you've copied the temp files to a new folder.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.